# Android layout left align without going off the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I want to have a TextView that can grow to fit its text content on the left and an ImageView on the right. I want the image to align directly to the right of the TextView, moving to the right as the text grows and stopping when it reaches the right edge of the screen.  I do not want the ImageView on the right of the screen to change size at all to accommodate the text as it grows further.  I have a simple relative layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Example text asdfasdf asdfasdf asldkj asdfasaaasdfdda"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text"
        android:minWidth="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/notification_bubble"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This pushes the ImageView to the right side of screen as the text fills in (correct) but then when the ImageView reaches the right side of the screen it shrinks, eventually to 0 (not what I want).  How do I prevent this shrinking?  minWidth is being ignored.

FYI, the above with the top level layout set to LinearLayout looks identical (lots of text, squished image).  If I set layout_weight="1" on the ImageView and layout_width="0dip" the image is compressed as well.

---

Onik posed a suitable solution to the problem, but it pointed out that really my question is an oversimplification.  I am actually not using 2 views in my real layout.  The TextView is a LinearLayout that is sizing itself to fit its content properly, but it is pushing the ImageView to the right (again, properly) and then causing it to shrink (again, what I am trying to get rid of).

Comment: I don't know what purpose the image is intended to, but you can reach this exactly result by setting `android:drawableRight="@drawable/notification_bubble"` attribute to `TextView`. After that `ImageView` can be removed. Repeat, it depends on how the image is going to be used.

Comment: That's a good solution, but this is actually an oversimplification of the problem.  The TextView in my real problem is actually a Layout with a bunch of views within.  I will edit to clarify.